# How is Android notification time format updated?

Tags: android

I'm using a custom RemoteView for AndroidNotification, and I would like to mimic the system behavior.

How does Android update its notification time format - do they ever change once they are set? How am I able to mimic this behavior?

Comment: I had my part of my question answered. However, that doesn't solve my problem.  
I have a RemoteViews with a custom view (using setContent). I would like a date or time to be displayed in my notification, mimicking behavior of native Android. I would achieve this using the API call (DateUtils.formatSameDayTime). the problem is, oncesetTextViewText is made on the RemoteView and notificationManager.notify is called, that's it, the text is permanent.




I would like a date or time dynamically changing based on time passed (over 24 hours would show a date). Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you are still looking for answers, given that you have provided one yourself. However, if you are looking to achieve your original goal you will probably want to

- Rebuild the RemoteView whenever the time changes (it's just way easier)
- Set up a BroadcastReceiver to catch the ticks of the clock so you know when the time has changed.

So, some code a bit like this:

```
class MyCleverThing extends Service (say) {

    // Your stuff here

    private static IntentFilter timeChangeIntentFilter;
    static {
        timeChangeIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        timeChangeIntentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);
        timeChangeIntentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
    }

    // Somewhere in onCreate or equivalent to set up the receiver
    registerReceiver(timeChangedReceiver, timeChangeIntentFilter);

    // The actual receiver
    private final BroadcastReceiver timeChangedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED) ||
            action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED))
        {
            updateWidgets();  // Your code to rebuild the remoteViews or whatever
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: A bit complicated but a legit solution.

Comment: It is - if there is a less complicated way of doing it (and it working consistently etc etc) I would love to see it. Thanks for the tick and to bounty, appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about the notification time format, but if you want to mimic their behaviour should have a look at the `DateUtils` class, especially the [formatSameDayTime](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#formatSameDayTime%28long,%20long,%20int,%20int%29) which I think does what you described.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to update the notification after being added unless .notify is called again with the same ID.

If dealing with time stamp, it is best to use the native Notification NotificationCompat.Builder without using RemoteViews.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you update your notification, do something as simple as this (24 hour time)...

```
public void updateNotifTime(RemoteViews customNotifView){
    Date currentTime = new Date();
    int mins = currentTime.getMinutes();
    String minString = "";
    if(mins<10){
       minString = "0";
    }
    minString += mins;
    customNotifView.setTextViewText(R.id.time, currentTime.getHours()+":"+minString);
}
```

Comment: I would like the notification to update by itself based on time elapsed, just like the native ones.